# How Can I Sort SQL Results From Smallest Index To Largest Index?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have a database that is sorted by ID. I want to echo out the 3 rows with the biggest id number but have them echoed out as

```
id = 5
id = 6
id = 7
```

as opposed to how

```
SELECT * FROM `userinfo`ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 3;
```

will echo out

```
id = 7
id = 6
id = 5
```

in PHP

Comment: Change `ASC` to `DESC` ?

Comment: Hi, and so: what is your issue ? What's your question ? You want to print it in php ?

Comment: @B001ᛦ maybe he wants to print id 5/6/7 instead of 7/6/5

Comment: If you want to echo in an ascending order you need to use `ASC`, otherwise `DESC`. But indeed it is not clear what you are trying to ask

Comment: lets say he has 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and he wants to display 5,6,7 so you need sticky bits solution

Comment: "...I have a database that is sorted by ID..." -- tables are **unsorted** bags of rows. Rows don't have inherent ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Use a derived table for limiting the result and sort again in the outer query.

```
SELECT *
       FROM (SELECT *
                    FROM `userinfo`
                    ORDER BY `id` DESC
                    LIMIT 3) x
       ORDER BY `id` ASC;
```